# Does Byte Buddy delete generated class files in Android storage afterwards?

Tags: android, delete-file, byte-buddy

I noticed that the classes created by Byte Buddy at run-time were written to data/data folder but after the application shutdown, those generated classes are still existing there.  Do we have to write code to delete those file ourselves or Byte Buddy has some api to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Ideally, you can provide a folder that is considered temporary by the system such that it is deleted automatically. Alternatively, you can [register a shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html) to delete a folder.

The problem is that Byte Buddy cannot know if the folder is also used for other purpuses. In this case, if Byte Buddy deleted your supplied folder, this would be unpleasant.